# Adding cordova plugin media-capture to meteor

Tags: cordova, meteor, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I want to add the media-capture plugin to my meteor app. I add the package with `meteor add cordova:org.apache.cordova.media-capture@0.3.4`. When I run `meteor run android` it won't load. Is there another way?

Comment: What do you mean by "won't load"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to start it up! The problem was that there wasn't a version 0.3.4 of media-capture available. I chose version 0.3.2 and it worked.